# Excel conditional sums dependant on relative cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with 3 different staff members. Each staff member has their own worksheet with all the clients they have worked for each week. I currently have a working Macro that will take a user inputted client code, then searches through each staff member and generates a client summary that will look something like the following

```
Client Code         Job               Time       Staff       
BW01                Some work         5          Tim
BW01                Some work         4          Tim
BW01                Some work         7.5        Jason
BW01                Some work         8          Frank
BW01                Some work         2.75       Frank
```

I am looking for a way to search through this list and add up each individual persons times. So Tim would be 9 hours, Jason 7.5, Frank 10.75 for example. I have achieved this with the following code,

```
Sub totalTime()

Dim i As Long
For i = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Range("I" & i) <> Range("I" & i + 1) Then
    Rows(i + 1).Insert
End If
Next i
    For Each numrange In Columns("G").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).Areas
        SUMADDR = numrange.Address(False, False)
        numrange.Offset(numrange.Count, 0).Resize(1, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & SUMADDR & ")"
        c = numrange.Count
    Next numrange
NoData:
Columns(3).Value = Columns(3).Value
End Sub
```

As thats the only way i can think to do it, however the total time needs to be printed elsewhere so hoping to do away with the adding a new line method and store each persons total in an array if possible.

Im not asking for someone to do this obviously, i just cant get my head around a way it could be done, if anyone has a better approach any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of the [SUMIFS function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumifs.php)?

Comment: Hadn't given it a thought, but that could do what im after nicely! Ill give it a crack thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use VBA, you could do something like code below. I pasted your data and my data range is A1:F6. Code checks all cells in Staff column and if Staff is Tim, Frank or Jason it adds his working time. At the end it shows total time in a given cell. Note numbers should be written with commas(or else use some time formatting), so I provided you Replace property.

```
Sub TotalTime_Staff()

Dim lastrow As Long, staff_member As String
Dim TimeTim As Double, TimeJason As Double, TimeFrank As Double

lastrow = Worksheets("Arkusz1").Cells(1, 4).End(xlDown).Row


For i = 1 To lastrow

    With Worksheets("Arkusz1")

        staff_member = .Cells(i, 4).Value

        .Cells(i, 3) = Replace(.Cells(i, 3), ".", ",")

        Select Case staff_member

            Case "Tim"
                TimeTim = TimeTim + .Cells(i, 3)

            Case "Jason"
                TimeJason = TimeJason + .Cells(i, 3)

            Case "Frank"
                TimeFrank = TimeFrank + .Cells(i, 3)

        End Select

    End With

Next i

With Worksheets("Arkusz1")
    .Cells(1, 6) = TimeTim
    .Cells(2, 6) = TimeJason
    .Cells(3, 6) = TimeFrank
End With

End Sub
```